# Jquery plugin get options from option

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the options from another set of options.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/menFB/1/) 
at the moment this is outputting the name of each option in `opt.social`. Instead I want it to fetch the actual HTML related to each option name.

Thus the idea is that in the future when a new social media site is built, this can easily be added via the plugin options without the need to edit the plugin.

Example:

```
$.each(opt.social, function(index, value) {
  html += "<li>" + value.name + "</li>";
});
```

I have tried

```
opt[value.name];
opt.value.name;
opt(value.name);
```

Full example:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.socialMedia = function (options) {

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {
        social: [
             { name: "facebook.like_large"},
             { name: "twitter.large"},
             { name: "googlePlus.large"}
        ],
        facebook: {
            like_large: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="false"></div>',
            like_small: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>',
            share: '<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="{url}" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&t={title}">Share</a>'
        },
        twitter: {
            large: '<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{url}" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>',
            small: '<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{url}">Tweet</a>'
        },
        googlePlus: {
            large: '<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="{url}"></div>',
            small: '<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="120" data-href="{url}"></div>'            
        }
    };

    var opt = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

    // Generate HTML
    $(this).append(generateHtml());

    function generateHtml() {            
        var html = '<ul>';

        $.each(opt.social, function(index, value) {
            html += "<li>" + value.name + "</li>";
        });

        html += '</ul>';            
        return html;
    }
}

  $("body").socialMedia();  

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You haven't been very specific about where the options come from and what exactly you want to get from them.

Comment: For each opt.social object, I want it the find the equivalent HTML option using its name.

Comment: OK answer updated - I think I get what you're trying to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that code, `opt.social` is an array of objects, each with a "name" property.

Thus,

```
var firstOptName = opt.social[0].name;
```

And so on.  The `opt.social` array should be indexed numerically. Now, `opt.googlePlus` is just an object with (in this case) two properties, so there's no array indexing involved:

```
var googleLarge = opt.googlePlus.large;
```

*edit* — if you want to just alter that loop to show the HTML:

```
$.each(opt.social, function(index, value) {
  var parts = value.name.split('.'), partVal = opts;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i)
    partVal = partVal[parts[i]];
  html += "<li>" + partVal + "</li>";
});
```

The trick is that those "name" properties are in the form of dotted "paths" through an object graph, and JavaScript does not have a built-in way of interpreting those. The code I wrote above walks through the object part by part (parts are separated by "." characters), starting from the outer "opts" object.

Comment: I want the plugin to work without manually declaring each social plugin from within the plugin. E.G you will be able to add your own social plugin via options without having to edit the plugin itself.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia I'm still not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but I'll extend my answer with a guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/menFB/3/), according to what I understood you wanted.

each `social` entry can contain the `name` of the social service and a default `widget` to use.

so your `defaults` can be like this:

```
social: [
  { name: 'facebook', widget : 'like_large'},
  { name: 'twitter', widget : 'large'},
  { name: 'googlePlus', widget : 'large'}
]
```

and your generateHTML() can be:

```
 $.each(opt.social, function(index, value) { 
   var default_widget = opt[value.name][value.widget];
   html += "<li>" + default_widget + "</li>"; 

   // or maybe:
   html += $('<li></li>').html(default_widget);
 });
```